# Flutter Timer call function

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to call a function every 5 minutes but from what I see, the timer waits 5 minutes and then calls the function. Shouldn't it call it once when the timer is set and then every 5 minutes after?

```
const time = const Duration(seconds: 300);
Timer.periodic(time, (Timer t) => _getData());
```

Comment: Dude its correct buy if you wanna call the function when the state-building first, then you should use `initState` and here you can write your code and plus your code also for call your function when screen started building then you should add `_getData()` also

Comment: Also you can set minutes to `Duration` directly: `Duration(minutes: 5)`.

Comment: Yes, it should call `_getData()` every 5 minutes.  Why do you think that it isn't?

Comment: Yeah ... but I need an initial call. Like this. Call when widget loads > call after 5 min > call after 5 min .... and so on. I don't think it calls when widget loads. I might be wrong. I'll do more testing.

Answer (score 0):

Add this lines in your app it will call the _getData() every  5 min in the app

```
   Timer _timerForInter;
    void initState() {
        _timerForInter = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 300), (result) {
        _getData()
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
final int timerMaxSeconds = 1800;
  int currentSeconds = 0;
  
  startTimeout([int milliseconds]) {
    var duration = interval;
    Timer.periodic(duration, (timer) {
      setState(() {
        print(timer.tick);
        currentSeconds = timer.tick;
        if (timer.tick >= timerMaxSeconds)
          timer.cancel();
         // submitDataToFirebase();
      });
    });
  }
```

and Call startTimeout like this

```
startTimeout(300);
```